# Excel macro - keep source formatting

Tags: excel, format, ms-office, vba

When I try to copy data between worksheets this is no problem, but when I try to copy the same data to a word document it loses its format. Is there a way to stop this?

```
' Copy all data from 1.xls to new.docx
Sheets("Design").Select
Range("A1:G50").Copy
appWD.Selection.Paste
```

Could it be something with PasteSpecial?

Thanks.

@Brown

```
Select Case Range("C19").Value
    Case 1
        Sheets("Info").Select
        Range("B7").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Design").Range("A" & x)
        x = x + 2
End Select
```

So this copies the data from cell C19(Sheet: Info) to cell B7(Sheet: Design)

```
' I open my word doc etc.
Sheets("Design").Select
Range("A1:E50").Copy
appWD.Selection.Paste
```

This selects sheet Design, copies everything and pastes this into a word doc. I lose my formatting, I'm also using XP, office 2007.

Comment: When I try this, this works fine, all formats are kept intact (using Office XP). I checked number formats and font colors. Can you reproduce this behaviour in a small test program?

Comment: Why didn't you look at the documentation of PasteSpecial, since you suggest it may be your solution (hint: it is, though I only have the experience of it with Excel).

Comment: I don't think "PasteSpcial" will help here, "Paste" should do it.

Comment: Still doesn't work for me though DocBrown. I get my data into Word, but the layout is horrid ..

Comment: Can you be a little bit more specific of what kind of layout you have and what you expect it should look like in word?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my simple test program

```
Sub test()
    Dim wrdApp As Word.Application
    Set wrdApp = New Word.Application
    Dim wrdDoc As Word.Document
    wrdApp.Documents.Add
    Set wrdDoc = wrdApp.ActiveDocument
    Range("A1:B1").Copy
    wrdApp.Selection.Paste
    wrdDoc.SaveAs "D:\tmp\myworddoc.doc"
End Sub
```

This works with Office XP (I don't have Office 2007 at hand). Cells A1:B1 contain formatted numbers. This one works fine on my machine, the created word doc contains a table with formatted numbers, too. Can you try it on yours to see if it works?

Comment: hmm indeed, this does work. I wonder why it doesn't work for me :s But thanks though.

Comment: @Tom: find out what is different between your situation and mine, and you are done :-)